# Wicket integration with some sort of CMS?

Tags: java, user-interface, content-management-system, integration, wicket

**Is there any possibility for integrating Wicket with a CMS?** 

I have been working with Wicket for 2 years already and I am aware of how new Components are created and how these should be distributed within packages.I also know the structure of a Wicket project,configurations,requirements.It is hardly for me to imagine that a Client could create a new page and add it to a menu from an GUI of a CMS.

*But anything worth asking ...*

Answer (score 1):

There are few:

- https://github.com/brix-cms/brix-cms/
- http://www.bricket.org/

Brix is being revived for Wicket 8.x!